Removing peeling latex paint from old lead paint
When removing peeling latex paint from old lead paint - do you have to remove the latex from the whole surface (bathroom ceiling) or just the peeling areas?

Can only remove the loose paint, but usually that leaves lines/ridges between the bonded paint and the lead paint.  Those lines should be sanded to smooth out the surfaces, but should not sand lead paint, which makes it very hard to smooth out the lines before painting again.

You can sand lead paint, you just have to do it wet and be really good at material control.  If it's even lead. Lead was used in a) bright yellow-red pigments and b) cheap lead paint where the maker was too cheap to use titanium dioxide.

Remove the loose paint. Clean the surfaces with TSP or similar degreaser. Skim coat the area with drywall compound to smooth the surface. Sand, prime and paint.
